# Enable Airplane Mode Onclick -Android

Tags: android

I have a toggle button in my project and i want is the togglebutton should turn on flight mode then AUTOMATICALLY turn it off after 5 sec. i found a code but i don't know how to modify it to work with a toggle button

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // check current state first
    boolean state = isAirplaneMode();
    // toggle the state
    toggleAirplaneMode(state);

    state = isAirplaneMode();
    // toggle the state
    toggleAirplaneMode(state);
    ser = new ServiceState();
    ser.setState(STATE_IN_SERVICE);
}
```

**toggle button**

```
toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tglbtn1);
toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (toggle.isChecked()) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "toggle button enabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "toggle button disabled",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});

}
}
```

Comment: what **exactly** is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this documentation, it's about the `ToggleButton` management on Android:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

May help you to understand how it works.

That said, what the purpose of deactivating/reactivating airplane mode so quickly?

To execute a task in x seconds, you can use the `Timer` class:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Or even better:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what **exactly** your method is doing, so I'm guessing a little bit with the details. But you should be able to fill the gaps:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // check current state first
    boolean state = isAirplaneMode();
    // toggle the state
    toggleAirplaneMode(state);

    state = isAirplaneMode();
    // toggle the state
    toggleAirplaneMode(state);
    ser = new ServiceState();
    ser.setState(STATE_IN_SERVICE);

    // you might want to disable the button here

    // change state back after 5s
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO actually change the state variable
            // and toggle back the airplane mode
            // if you disabled the button, enable it here
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: what is your problem with integrating? my answer is just about the delayed code execution.